# SQL query: Regex select text between HTML tags with attributes

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

The person table has a description column which contains text in html format.

The query should return the id and the description for each person, removing all the html formatting.

```
select id, REGEXP_EXTRACT(description, r"REGEX_GOES_HERE") from person;
```

Example of one of the descriptions:

```
<p class="position-body__description" data-section="pastPositions">• Lorem Ipsum dorem posum <br>This is my test html regex.<br> • Provided general HR support of multiple team members’ development, technical and certification training.<br>• Demonstrated experience in an administrative support role managing multiple requests simultaneously.</p>
```

Expected output:

1, Lorem Ipsum dorem posumThis is my test html regex. • Provided general HR support of multiple team members’ development, technical and certification training.• Demonstrated experience in an administrative support role managing multiple requests simultaneously.

Comment: I love a good Lorem Ipsum. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried (?<=>)([\w\s]+)(?=<\/) Though this doesn't work for all edge cases @JacobH

Comment: @JacobH Also this one <p([^>]*)>((.|\n)*?)<\/p>

Answer (score 4):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(description, r'<.*?>', '') description_without_formatting 
FROM `project.dataset.person`
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.person` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '<p class="position-body__description" data-section="pastPositions">• Lorem Ipsum dorem posum <br>This is my test html regex.<br> • Provided general HR support of multiple team members’ development, technical and certification training.<br>• Demonstrated experience in an administrative support role managing multiple requests simultaneously.</p>' description
)
SELECT id, 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(description, r'<.*?>', '') description_without_formatting 
FROM `project.dataset.person`
```

with result

```
Row id  description_without_formatting   
1   1   • Lorem Ipsum dorem posum This is my test html regex. • Provided general HR support of multiple team members’ development, technical and certification training.• Demonstrated experience in an administrative support role managing multiple requests simultaneously.
```